# Electron can't find resources

Tags: angular, electron

I am trying to build a super simple app with *Angular* and *Electron* and to set it up as much from scratch as I can (just for learning purposes). I've set up a simple Angular project based on [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/setting-up-angular-from-scratch-1f518c65d8ab) and it runs fine in a browser.

I then installed Electron and added `electron-main.js` from [this quick start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js)

> **You can clone my (very basic) project as it stands if you think you can help:** `git clone https://popClingwrap@bitbucket.org/popClingwrap/psutil-desktop.git`

Now, when I run `electron electron-main.js` the app starts and `index.html` is loaded but I get failures for everything else - my `main.js` and modules located in `node_modules`

If I pack everything up with WebPack and use the resulting `bundle.js` then everything works but I don't want to have to bundle with every change as I'm developing.

I'm guessing that Electron needs some config to tell it where to find required resources?
Can anyone give details on why this is the case and how to fix it?

Also if anyone has any great tips on tools to help building/debuggingElectron apps that would be great! I've built working projects in the past but they were all started with the `Angular-CLI` and I'm keen to do this one with minimal bloat and actually try to understand the basics of the process.

Cheers in advance

Comment: Choosing not to use webpack is kind of strange from my own perspective (moreover, as long as it's ready to use, you SHOULD use it). Anyway. In your index.html you will find some includes (usually from either dist/ or from ./ or / if base href is defined): ensure that your main scripts and images are loaded correctly and ensure that your main javascript file (the one you launch with electron) is pointing to the correct resources. Webpack does that for you already, and that's why you should use it. That said, if the "every change" is the issue here, just disable the webpack's watch option.

Comment: I'm not really *choosing* not to use webpack. At the moment I'm just following tutorials and reading articles and have ended up at the point I'm at. Regarding your other points everything seems to load fine when I run in browser but not in an electron window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to do

> npm start

which will start a server(which is required to serve resource files) in watch mode.

Then inside electron-main.js change the "loadUrl" line as follwing

> mainWindow.loadURL('http://127.0.0.1:8080/')

Then do

> npm run electron

Everything should be fine.

I am attaching a screenshot of your working project(with the changed message) on my local machine.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! A single line solution, just what I like :) I'm confused though, does Electron not start its own server, why is live-server required?

Comment: @popClingwrap No, it does not. It just behaves like a browser (with so many added features though) and loads your application based on the URL provided.